# iText 7 - HTMLWorker and ParseXHtml missing

Tags: itext, itext7

I was not able to find HTMLWorker, ParseXHtml, Document and other related classes in iText 7 (unlike in iText 5). Can anybody tell me how to convert HTML file to PDF using iText 7 ?

Thank you,
Sumanasa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `HTMLWorker` has been deprecated many years ago. In iText 5 you should really, *really* use `XMLWorker`. iText 5 is EOL (only security updates, no added functionality) so please migrate to iText 7.
2. For iText 7, use the add-on **pdfHTML**. See Alexey's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

iText `pdfHTML` module has been released as a replacement for `XmlWorker`.
C# version can be downloaded from the [NuGet Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfhtml/). Java version can be downloaded from the [Artifactory](https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/simple/General/releases/com/itextpdf/html2pdf).

The main class you are looking for is `HtmlConverter`. It has a lot of static method overloads for converting `html` either to a list of elements to be future added to layout structures, to a whole `com.itextpdf.layout.Document` instance, or right to the `.pdf` file.

Example of converting `.html` file to `.pdf`:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(htmlFilePath), new File(outPdfFilePath));
```

Example of converting html to layout elements:

```
String html = "<p>Hello world!</p>";
List<IElement> lst = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(html);
```

Also, `pdfHTML` now supports `@media` rules, so you might want to provide a configuration which will be used for applying CSS, for instance to use `@media print` instructions, you would need to set up `MediaDeviceDescription` accordingly:

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties()
     .setMediaDeviceDescription(new MediaDeviceDescription(MediaType.PRINT));
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(htmlPath), new File(outPdfPath), properties);
```

To specify the set of fonts you would like to use when converting HTML to PDF, you can also set up a `FontProvider`:

```
FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider();
fontProvider.addDirectory(fontsDir)
properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
```

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to founder of iText Group, `HTMLWorker` is deprecated long time ago and its intention was not to convert complete HTML pages. It basically does not know web page consists of `<head>` and `<body>` section.

`XMLWorker` was meant as a generic framework to **parse XML**. To avoid these conflicts, **iText 7** came into play with `convertToPdf` function which is capable of converting HTML into PDF.

Following would be the code snippet.

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest));
```

Add your HTML coding or `.html` file into first parameter and provide file location to save HTML into PDF in provided location (file path).